# Any tips or ideas on how to design this optical art that only uses orthogonal lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, technique

I am just experimenting on new techniques and op art was something that always pique my interest. Any idea on where to start or how to even get the lines to aligned like this?

[image]

Source: H.P. Lovecraft, l'expo qui rend fou by Swiss design firm Notter + Vigne (http://www.notter-vigne.ch/fre/l_expo_qui_rend_fou)

Comment: I am not sure that there is a trick. It's all just lines drawn at 45 degrees. If you hold down the shift key in Illustrator it will constrain the lines to 0, 45, 90 and 135 degrees. You can draw with a sketch underneath. You can draw them from scratch or you could start by making a clean pattern of lines and then delete and manipulate afterwards.

Comment: I think your question will get closed because your title is too broad... If you would like information on how to align lines like this, you should probably edit your question :) Very cool stuff!

Comment: Just for kicks... another layer of illusion can be added by using thickness: https://citizencosmos.tumblr.com/post/167201456020/goodjolt-just

Comment: I'd suggest an edit detailing what you've tried already.

Comment: Tip 1: you can actually rotate illustrators grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to do a whole detailed tutorial as it would take too long. But basically this is the procedure I would use to recreate such an image.

1. Enable the Grid and Snap to Grid, draw two horizontal lines and create a step blend so the lines match up with the grid.
2. Copy the blend, and on a new layer, paste in place, then rotate 90°.
3. At a 45° angle, draw a skull using the pen tool to draw line segments using the Snap to Grid. *See the black shape to the left in the example below
4. Use that shape and apply it as a transparency mask to each blend, each mask being the inverse of the other.

*Here's the example, showing a copy of the transparency mask in black (on the left), and applied to the two blends (on the right).

[image]

Here's the arrangement of the layers in the main document

[image]

5. Many of the connecting lines will have thinner strokes. You can rectify these by drawing straight line segments over the top.

[image]

6. Finally, select all, and rotate the whole thing -45°. Group everything, then apply a rectangular clipping mask to finish.

[image]

Comment: It may be easier if you rotate the grid in options

Comment: I had an idea on how to execute this but couldn't find a tutorial online on how to do it, thanks for breaking it down!

Answer (score 3):

Wow - I can't actually look at that pic without it hurting.

Simple effect though - create a layer with parallel lines, create a copy of that layer using the skull shape as a mask with lines rotated by 90 degrees, then manually decide on your line endings.

Comment: You can actually do this autimetically with a 45 degree turn object mosaic some masking and done;) Oh and welcome to GD